# Unit test for catch statement in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito, junit-jupiter

There is a class named `ClientFactory` which is extending `ClientInfo`. I have to write unit test for this class. It is easy to cover try block but I am not able to write test case which will cover catch blocks. How can I achieve this?

```
public class ClientFactory extends ClientInfo {
    private static final String PROVIDER_PATH = "com.devo.com.providers";

    public ClientFactory(List<String> providers) {
        super(getProviderListOfObjects(providers));
    }

    private static List<Provider> getProviderListOfObjects(List<String> providers) {
        List<Provider> providersObject = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String provider : providers) {
            provider = PROVIDER_PATH + "." + provider;
            try {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(provider);
                Provider providerObj = (Provider) c.newInstance();
                providersObject.add(providerObj);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                String message = String.format("Provider %s not found in package %s.", provider, PROVIDER_PATH);
                log.error(message);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                String message = String.format("Unable to create new instance of %s class.", provider);
                log.error(message);
            }
        }
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(providersObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: " It is easy to cover try block but I am not able to write test case which will cover catch blocks." - Are you asking how to mock the `log` property interactions, or something else?  If the former, what is the declared type of `log`?

Comment: It might be possible we are calling other services in catch block. How we can test for that? However, In my situation I just wanted to make sure that test coverage is 100%.

Comment: When you write test code, you can check for side effects, outputs, etc. to validate whether the underlying code did what you wanted it to do. In this case, the `catch` blocks both have no output or side effects other than calling `log.error()`. So, as it is written, perhaps you could mock `log`, call the method (`getProviderListOfObjects`), and then check whether `error()` was invoked on the mocked `log` object (and check the string message, too).

Comment: "It might be possible we are calling other services in catch block. How we can test for that?" - That will depend on how you are calling those services.  You could be invoking a static method, you could be invoking an instance method on an object created in the catch block or on an object injected into the CUT.  The details will affect how to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: What code must be written in test file so that control reaches to second catch block? I was thinking about mocking `newInstance() ` and throwing specific exception but it is not recommended to mock `Class.newInstance`.

Comment: "What code must be written in test file so that control reaches to second catch block?" - You could pass in a class name that exists but you don't have access to instantiate, for example, a non-public class that is in a package other than the class that is attempting to create the instance.